# Error while running make command for srilm

Tags: srilm

While executing make command, I recieve the following error:

/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP//lib/i686-m64/libmisc.a(File.o): In function `File::~File()':
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP/misc/src/File.cc:127: undefined reference to`libiconv_close'
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP//lib/i686-m64/libmisc.a(File.o): In function `File::reopen(char const*, char const*)':
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP/misc/src/File.cc:167: undefined reference to`libiconv_close'
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP//lib/i686-m64/libmisc.a(File.o): In function `File::reopen(char const*)':
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP/misc/src/File.cc:217: undefined reference to`libiconv_close'
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP//lib/i686-m64/libmisc.a(File.o): In function `File::reopen(char const*, unsigned long, int)':
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP/misc/src/File.cc:249: undefined reference to`libiconv_close'
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP//lib/i686-m64/libmisc.a(File.o): In function `File::reopen(std::string&, int)':
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP/misc/src/File.cc:273: undefined reference to`libiconv_close'
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP//lib/i686-m64/libmisc.a(File.o): In function `File::fgetsUTF8(char*, int)':
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP/misc/src/File.cc:387: undefined reference to`libiconv'
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP/misc/src/File.cc:345: undefined reference to `libiconv_open'
/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP/misc/src/File.cc:349: undefined reference to`libiconv_open'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
test -f ../bin/i686-m64/ngram
make[2]: *** [../bin/i686-m64/ngram] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP/lm/src'
make[1]: *** [release-programs] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory`/home/cse/phd/16071009/NLP'
make: *** [World] Error 2
[16071009@compute-01 NLP]$

Answer (score 1):

The -liconv appears nowhere in the link command, so that's why you're 
getting the undefined references.  Try putting:

```
 SYS_LIBRARIES = -L<path-to-libiconv_install> -liconv
```

For example, if you install srilm on Ubuntu x64, edit this file: common/Makefile.site.i686-m64. Make sure the -L option points to the directory that has the libiconv.so or libiconv.a file.

For me, libiconv install srilm on Ubuntu 18.04 x64 using make are locate on `/usr/local/lib`. So I add following line to common/Makefile.site.i686-m64:

```
SYS_LIBRARIES = -L/usr/local/lib -liconv
```

Solution from: http://mailman.speech.sri.com/pipermail/srilm-user/2014q3/001694.html